# PHP Format String to Number

Tags: php

I have this HTML code:

```
<span class="price">Price: <font class="rosu_12px_bold">2'099<sup>99</sup></font> EUR</span>
```

and i managed to extract the price: 2'09999

I cant catch the sup tag and insert a .

Now, in my database, i can only store real numbers

The value extracted is not a number so i get the 0 value, when trying to insert this value.

I can only insert it this way: 2099.99

I can never know what my extracted value looks like, so i need a solution to format it.

Comment: Once you have the string in a variable, you will need to regex the data out of it. It's not going to be amazingly pretty though depending on how much variation there is in your data.

Comment: Remove all non digits and divide by 100. like @Fluffeh said, if there is variation than this won't work either.

Comment: i cant detect if <sup> tag is there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $abc="2'099";
    echo preg_replace('/[^0-9]/i', '', $abc);
    ?>
```

Edit:
Remember this will replace period(.) as well.

Yet another edit: You can use strip tags to strip html tags

```
<?php
$abc="<font class='rosu_12px_bold'>2'099<sup>99</sup></font>";
echo preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/i', '', strip_tags($abc));
?>
```

Edit:
But 99 between sup tags might denote the lower denomination of the currency may be 99 cents. In this case above example will not work.

Yet another edit,
Before using strip tags, you can replace sup tag with period(.) and then use strip_tags, if you want to maintain the lower denomination of the currency.

Hope this helps

Comment: If he is working with the full example HTML is stated this will not work since it will catch `rosu_12px_bold` as well, it is unclear as to whether it he is attempting to regex out HTML or not.

Comment: the thing is that the main app is a bookmarklet, and i use highlighter to select tags from DOM, and a special function extracts the values within the selected area, so i dont know what tags are in there, i only get the value; this is one partial solution, but i need the entire number, even the 99 cents are very important here. i think i got it, i will post the answer soon, i hope

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian If the sup tag isnt there what would you use as the deliminator?

Comment: on every eShop, somehow, they print the product price, using also cents if price is like that; prices may be like 1.234,99 or 2'345.99 or 3'456<sup>99</sup> and my problem is that i have to catch 1234.99 instead of 123.456; 1234.99 is the right number to insert in the database

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian Do an if statement to isolate using the a preg_match for <sup> then run one of the answers, that will create the full solution, prolly easier than trying to make a CPU heavy regex to do an OR

Comment: for higher denomination there is no problem at all, the above code will work, the problem is in lower denomination whether it comes as .99 or it comes as <sup>99</sup> or sometimes even different format. You have to make a standard pattern so that lower denominations are formatted one or another form from the pattern. You can't manupulate these thing unless you know the pattern

Comment: also, if sup is not there, they will manage to print the price like : 1.456.99 or 1234,99 or 1.234 or 1,234 or 1234; they will print the entire price, somehow; i just have to catch the number and format it to my needs

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian Yea I would make an initial if preg_match to isolate where the <sup> tag exists, run the answer and then do an else where it just gets the number straight as normal without the tags around it.

Comment: @Sammaye after my bookmarklet highlighter extract the value, i only get something like 1'23499 or my dream case 2'345.99, i dont know what tags were present

Comment: the thing is that the owners could have inserted special custom html tags, tags that they have created, so i cant say that everyone will use sup tag; why not abc tag ? my main problem is that i have to find a way to format the string to a valid real number each time; nomather how my string looks like

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian Well take into account that a number can be like: `<i>23<i>,<b>56</b>,<sup>67</sup>.<strong style='text-align:left;'>56</strong>` this is a much more complex problem than we originally thought...

Comment: that's my point ! i dont kow what tags are present, i only know the final concatenated value beetween the tags

Comment: let me put it this way: i selected a area and i got the value: 1'23499; this would be ok in the following format: 1.234,99 and when inserted in the database i need 1234.99; if you look closer, you cant identify the 99 cents; and i need to avoid the value 123.999 from being saved to db :d simple no ?

Answer (score 0):

I only get strings like `1'23499` or `1.99989` or `1'345'99` or `1'234.99` or other formats.

The issue is how to get the 99 cents?

Involved in these values are the following chars:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 . , '
```

in any combination possible

My solution is:

1. Replace everything which is not a number `0 - 9` with **`.`** (*dot*)
2. Parse the string, from position 0 to strlen-1 and from where the first **`.`** (*dot*) is found, from 3 to 3 characters try and insert a **`.`** (*dot*). If the end of the string has been reached, avoid inserting .
3. Find position of last **`.`** (*dot*) inserted and remove all the other  **`.`** (*dot*)s .

The Result should be the number 1234.99.